# Deploying Python package on Anaconda with TravisCI

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my Python package on Anaconda using TravisCI. I've already set up the PyPi deployment, which runs fine. This is the related part of the  `travis.yml` file:

```yaml
deploy:
  provider: pypi
  username: "__token__"
  password:
    secure: ......
  on:
    tags: true
  distributions: "sdist bdist_wheel"
  skip_existing: true

after_deploy:
  - conda install conda-build
  - conda install anaconda-client
  - bash .ci/conda_upload.sh
```

The error happens in `.ci/conda_upload.sh`. Here is `conda_upload.sh`:

```sh
USER=myusername

mkdir ~/conda-bld
conda config --set anaconda_upload no
export CONDA_BLD_PATH=~/conda-bld
ls -l
conda build .

find $CONDA_BLD_PATH/ -name *.tar.bz2 | while read file
do
    echo $file
    anaconda -t $CONDA_UPLOAD_TOKEN upload -u $USER $file --force
done
```

The error message I get happens at `conda build .`, it cannot find `setup.py` file. However the previous `ls -l` call clearly indicates that there is a `setup.py` file there:

```
...
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis     1190 Aug 15 09:42 setup.py
...
```

I also included

```yaml
build:
  script_env:
   - CONDA_BLD_PATH
```

in the `meta.yaml` file.

Here is the full output I get on Travis:

```
WARNING:conda_build.metadata:No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.11

Adding in variants from internal_defaults

INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults

Attempting to finalize metadata for pysprint

INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for pysprint

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done

Solving environment: ...working... done

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done

Solving environment: ...working... done

BUILD START: ['pysprint-0.12.1-py38_0.tar.bz2']

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done

Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##
  environment location: /home/travis/conda-bld/pysprint_1597484753718/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    # deleted this section to save space

Preparing transaction: ...working... done

Verifying transaction: ...working... done

Executing transaction: ...working... done

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done

Solving environment: ...working... done

/home/travis/conda-bld/pysprint_1597484753718/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/bin/python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

source tree in: /home/travis/conda-bld/pysprint_1597484753718/work

export PREFIX=/home/travis/conda-bld/pysprint_1597484753718/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl

export BUILD_PREFIX=/home/travis/conda-bld/pysprint_1597484753718/_build_env

export SRC_DIR=/home/travis/conda-bld/pysprint_1597484753718/work

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/travis/miniconda/bin/conda-build", line 11, in <module>

    sys.exit(main())

  File "/home/travis/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 474, in main

    execute(sys.argv[1:])

  File "/home/travis/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 463, in execute

    outputs = api.build(args.recipe, post=args.post, test_run_post=args.test_run_post,

  File "/home/travis/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 208, in build

    return build_tree(absolute_recipes, config, stats, build_only=build_only, post=post,

  File "/home/travis/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 2859, in build_tree

    packages_from_this = build(metadata, stats,

  File "/home/travis/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 1994, in build

    utils.check_call_env(cmd, env=env, rewrite_stdout_env=rewrite_env,

  File "/home/travis/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 405, in check_call_env

    return _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ('call', *popenargs, **kwargs)

  File "/home/travis/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 385, in _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ

    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, _args)

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/bin/bash', '-o', 'errexit', '/home/travis/conda-bld/pysprint_1597484753718/work/conda_build.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

The problem seems to be that the environment location is set to

```
environment location: /home/travis/conda-bld/pysprint_1597484753718/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl
```

but I can't figure out how to solve this. I'm pretty new to linux environments and shell scripting, I'd appreciate if anyone could help me out.

EDIT:
Contents of `meta.yaml`:

```yaml
{% set name = "pysprint" %}
{% set version = "0.12.1" %}

package:
  name: "{{ name|lower }}"
  version: "{{ version }}"

source:
  url: "https://pypi.io/packages/source/{{ name[0] }}/{{ name }}/{{ name }}-{{ version }}.tar.gz"
  sha256: 5fee159c59c81fd31957e23bbd292bcfc1c947583f27eda7f4215594ec898ddd

build:
  script_env:
   - CONDA_BLD_PATH

requirements:
  host:
    - matplotlib
    - numpy >=1.16.6
    - pandas
    - pip
    - python
    - scipy

test:
  imports:
    - pysprint
```

Comment: What's the complete contents of your `meta.yaml` and `build.sh` if you have one?

Comment: @darthbith `build.sh`: `$PYTHON setup.py install `. In `meta.yaml` : package version, name, requirements, script env variable, and test imports. If you need the full file I can update the question. Locally conda build succeeds with the specified `meta.yaml` and `setup.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `deploy` section somehow messes up the conda deployment. I changed the `after_deploy` section to `before_deploy` and it works.

```yaml
before_deploy:
  - conda install conda-build
  - conda install anaconda-client
  - bash .ci/conda_upload.sh

deploy:
  provider: pypi
  username: "__token__"
  password:
    secure: ......
  on:
    tags: true
  distributions: "sdist bdist_wheel"
  skip_existing: true
```

However it is not clear to me at all what causes the issue.